# Java Simple Reference : Error

Tags: java

Actually I don't know what is the problem. Please understand me that I'm bigginer. Let me show you code :

**In Class A, There is a code below :**

```
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {"aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa"},
                {"bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb"},
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
```

**In Class B, Adding another table row. like :**

```
    DefaultTableModel model  = (DefaultTableModel)ToddlerGUI.jTable1.getModel();    
    model.addRow({"ccc","ccc","ccc","ccc"});
```

But Eclipse tells me there is an error(you know, red line)

> The method addRow(Vector) in the type DefaultTableModel is not
>   applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, String)

Anyone know what is problem?

Comment: You're passing four strings to a method that expects a vector? try `addRow( new String[] { "ccc", "ccc", "ccc", "ccc" } );`

Comment: Well `model.addRow({"ccc","ccc","ccc","ccc"});` is *syntactically* invalid to start with. If you want to create a string array, you need to do so explicitly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method invocation `model.addRow({"ccc","ccc","ccc","ccc"});` to `model.addRow(new String[]{"ccc","ccc","ccc","ccc"});`. That should do for you.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax { "ccc","ccc","ccc","ccc" } used ONLY for declaration. NOT use for passing parameter in a method.

For example:

```
String[] strs = { "ccc","ccc","ccc","ccc" }; // VALID
```

BUT

```
model.addRow( {"ccc","ccc","ccc","ccc" } ); // INVALID
```